# Generic method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, subtype

Sorry for the yet another "Java generic method is not applicable" question.  I would like to know what am I missing in my understanding:

1. `List<E>` is a subtype of `Collection<E>`
   --> meaning, `List<String>` is a subtype of `Collection<String>`
2. Suppose A extends B, `List<A>` is *not* a subtype of `List<B>`
   --> but in this case, there's only one type `T` (or `String`), so I don't see how the Substitution Principle can explain my problem?

**Problem Code**:

```
private <T, K> void genericAddToMapOfLists(HashMap<K, Collection<T>> mapOfLists, 
    K key, T value) {
    if (mapOfLists.containsKey(key)) {
        mapOfLists.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
        newList.add(value);
        mapOfLists.put(key, newList);
    }
}

private void parseToFruitList(HashMap<String, List<String>> fruit_colors,
        String fruitName) {
    String color = "";
    genericAddToMapOfLists(fruit_colors, fruitName, color);
}
```

**Error**:

```
The method genericAddToMapOfLists(HashMap<K,Collection<T>>, K, T) in the type MyGroceryStore is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String,List<String>>, String, String)
```

The code works when I change the method signature to `genericAddToMapOfLists(HashMap<K,List<T>>, K, T)`.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that "`List<String>` is a subtype of `Collection<String>`".  And if `A` extends `B`, `List<A>` is *not* a subtype of `List<B>`.

Taking that one step further, a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` is not a `HashMap<String, Collection<String>>`.

The same reasoning applies, where `A` is `List` and `B` is `Collection`.  If a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` was a `HashMap<String, Collection<String>>`, then you could `put` a `Vector<String>` into a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` by assigning it to a `HashMap<String, Collection<String>>`, even though a `Vector` isn't a `List`, and so it's not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the problem you are explaining in your second point.

> Suppose `A` extends `B`, `List<A>` is not a subtype of `List<B>`

In this case your method expects

```
HashMap<?, Collection<?>>
```

but you are giving it

```
HashMap<?, List<?>>
```

`List` extends `Collection`, but `HashMap<?, List>` is not a subtype of `HashMap<?, Collection>`

(I'm not using `?` as a wildcard, we just don't care about it right now)